# Least number of rides

Tags: algorithm, routes

I'm trying to solve this problem using an algorithm for at least a week but to no avail. I have a set of roads (1,2,3,...) and for each road there can be at least 1 vehicle that can pass (A,B,C,...). My problem is how to get the least number of rides for one to take to reach one road to another. For example:

```
road | vehicle(s)
  1  |  A,B
  2  |  A,B,C
  3  |  C,D
  4  |  C,D
  5  |  D,E
```

The output should be:

```
from 1, ride A or B to 2
from 2, ride C to 4
from 4, ride D to 5
```

The policy here is to exhaust one ride as much as possible, but the output should have the least number of ride changes.

Example 2:

```
road | vehicle(s)
  1  |  A,B
  2  |  A,B,C
  3  |  C,D
  4  |  C,D
  5  |  A,E
  6  |  E,F
  7  |  F
  8  |  F,H
  9  |  F,G
  10 |  F,G
  11 |  F
  12 |  F,G
  13 |  G,H
  14 |  H
```

Output:

```
from 1, ride A to 5
from 5, ride E to 6
from 6, ride F to 8
from 8, ride H to 14
```

Please help me to write the algorithm for the problem. I need to solve this for my project. Thanks!

PS: If you need other examples or clarification, just tell me in the comments below.

Comment: Are you always trying to ride from road 1 to road N?

Comment: @JOhn Yes, from the first road to the last road

Comment: Supply more of the question, add some information about the topic of routing. Your question is unclear because it lacks context. What homework is this for?  what subject? what's the topic etc

Comment: Any requirements concerning time/memory complexity? Any limitation for the size of the input data?

Comment: @julkiewicz it doesn't have any requirements on time/memory complexity nor on the size of the input data

Comment: I don't really understand something. If I arrive to a node N and I want to use ride R, is it always available? Or is it possible that I "left" the ride in another node and therefore cannot use it?

Comment: @julkiewicz I don't understand your first question. to the second, Yes, You should only ride a vehicle once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to think about this problem is to model it as a graph search problem.  For each of the different vehicles v, construct a graph G<sub>v</sub> whose nodes are all of the roads in the network with arcs between the nodes that are connected by vehicle v.  For example, in your first example, the graph G<sub>A</sub> would have five nodes, of which there is only a connection from node 1 to node 2, while the graph G<sub>C</sub> would have five nodes with edges from 2 to 3, 3 to 4, and 4 to 2.

Now, consider the final graph G constructed as follows.  G is formed by taking all of the graphs G<sub>v</sub> for all of the vehicles v (meaning that there are multiple copies of each node in the original graph), then adding edges between corresponding nodes in the different graphs if there are multiple different vehicles that all reach a road.  For example, in the graph G for the original problem, you would have G contain subgraphs G<sub>A</sub> and G<sub>B</sub>, ..., G<sub>E</sub>.  Since road 1 is serviced by both vehicles A and B, you would add an edge between the nodes for road 1 in the graphs G<sub>A</sub> and G<sub>B</sub>, and since road 2 is serviced by vehicles A, B, and C, there would be edges connecting all of the road 2 nodes for subgraphs G<sub>A</sub>, G<sub>B</sub>, and G<sub>C</sub>.

You are interested in minimizing the number of transfers you need to make, and so we'd like to set up some costs in this graph that measure that.  In particular, we say that any edge contained completely in one of the subgraphs G<sub>v</sub> has cost zero, since once you're on a vehicle of a given type you don't need to make any changes to move around the roads the vehicle services.  However, we assign a cost of one to each of the edges linking the subgraphs for different vehicles, since following this sort of edge would mean that you're changing which vehicle you're using.  If you now trace out any path in this graph, the total cost of that path is the number of vehicle changes you make.

To finalize the construction, we need to have some way of finding a cost from the starting road to the destination.  To do this, we'll add two new nodes s and t to the graph representing the start and end of the journey.  Node s will have cost-zero directed edges to the first road of each of the subgraphs, since when you start off the journey you can pick any of the vehicles as your first step.  Similarly, every subgraph's node for the final road will have a zero-cost edge to t, since once you arrive at the destination road it doesn't matter what vehicle you're in.

In this setup, any path from s to t has a cost equal to the total number of transfers you need to make.  Finding the shortest path in this graph from s to t therefore gives you both the route to take and the cost of that path.  You can solve this using Dijkstra's algorithm, for example.

The runtime of this algorithm isn't stellar, but it's still polynomial time.  Suppose that there are n roads and m different vehicles.  The graph we create will have m different subgraphs in it, each of which is for one vehicle, and in the worst case these graphs have O(n<sup>2</sup>) edges in them.  If we then link together all the corresponding nodes of these subgraphs where you can change lines, then in the worst case there will be O((mn)<sup>2</sup>) such edges, since there are m graphs of n nodes that all might be connected to one another.  We thus have a graph with O(mn) nodes and O((mn)<sup>2</sup>) edges, so we can run Dijkstra's algorithm in O((mn)<sup>2</sup> + mn log mn) time.

The main idea that I think is important to take away from this problem is that you can often solve problems about finding paths in graphs subject to certain constraints by creating a new graph formed out of multiple copies of the old graph and then coming up with a good edge-cost function for that graph.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I assumed here that you cannot go to a lower-numbered road so in Gc there are only 2 edges, 2 to 3, and 3 to 4. Will this assumption help reduce the running time?

Comment: @Jairo- Yes, but not asymptotically.  The number of arbitrary edges among n nodes is n(n-1), whereas if you can only go from lower nodes to higher nodes it's n(n-1)/2 (since half of them go from high to low).  So you get the same asymptotic (big-O) complexity, but in practice it will be faster.

Comment: To whoever downvoted - can you elaborate on what's wrong with this answer?

Comment: Thanks @templatetypedef! I did it, but I have a problem here. Only one of the possible rides are included, like in the first example, the journey started at ride 'A'. But I want to include ride 'B' to. And it is possible also to have other multiple rides in the journey itself.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying... Can you clarify that last comment?

Comment: In Example 1, it is possible to start with either ride 'A' or 'B', so in the output those 2 should be listed together. But in the solution you gave me, it only considers the ride 'A' (though the output is still correct).

Comment: Ah, I see.  I think this could be done by taking a look at the resulting path, and for each edge followed noting all possible transit lines you could take along that edge.  That is, once you know the shortest path, you can just augment the result by taking each edge you picked and saying what other transit lines run along that edge.